# algorithm with $n \log_2 (n) /2$ comparisons

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algorithm that compares pairs. For given natural numbers $x_1, ..., x_n$ $\mathcal{A}$ gives a permutation $\pi$ with $x_{\pi(1)} \leq \space... \leq x_{\pi(n)}$, all comparisons are based on "Is $x_i \leq x_j$?". Show that an input $x_1^*, ..., x_n^*$ exists for which $\mathcal{A}$ requires at least $n \log_2 (n) /2$ comparisons.

---

I don't really know where to start but I read that  the worst case for an algorithm that compares pairs is $\log_2 n!$. I guess I'm done if $n \log_2 (n) /2 \leq \log_2 n!$. But $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\frac{n\log_2(n)}{2}}{\log_2 n!} = \infty$ and this means that n $\log_2 (n) /2$ is bigger right? I tried to graph both functions in desmos and $\log_2 n!$ seems to be bigger but the function suddenly stops at around $170$. I'm super confused right now, shouldn't $\log_2 n!$ be defined for all positive integers? Or are the numbers too big for desmos? My limit also doesn't seem to make any sense, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: the numbers are probably too big for desmos. You're entirely right that $\log_2 n!$ is defined for all natural $n$ (and by using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) we can extend it to all positive reals).

Comment: For instance, you can ask for $\log_2 (200!)$ on wolframalpha. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log_2+%28200%21%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is right. Also, using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

\begin{equation}
n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n
\end{equation}

you can prove your inequality.